# Is it possible to use Adsense to show adverts for a period of time in an overlay

Tags: google-adsense

On my Android device, on many free applications, I have to sit through adverts. I'm hoping most understand the situation so I won't elaborate.

I'd like to achieve the same in a web browser.

The idea will be, some one uses my "free" service, and after some user action (such as clicking a Save button) they see an advert for *n* seconds (which can't be dismissed). After the timer counts down and hits 0 the advert can be dismissed and the user can progress. On our mobile phones this is quite common but, I've not seen this in use on the web. I'd like to have a play and see what the reaction is.

I am aware users can use some type of ad blocker (or similar) which may render this useless however, that isn't a concern for me.

Is this possible with Adsense? My question is not how to code it in. I'm able to do that and have. The issue is that Adsense won't show because Adsense loads at the point the page loads, but my overlay shows in a non-deterministic manner. I'm sure my goal here is not new but I'm unable to complete it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but this is forbidden by Google's rules.

See this discussion on [Google support forum](https://support.google.com/adsense/forum/AAAAKDuOfxQpD0zm66Ibe0/?hl=en&msgid=dew-nAc-AQAJ&gpf=d/msg/adsense/pD0zm66Ibe0/dew-nAc-AQAJ), your content must always be the main focus of the page, and AdSense might stop serving ads if they feel the page is not valuable enough to justify the number of ads.

As a user I would certainly close the tab if I had to wait *n* seconds before to load a content and I would grab my info from another source. The experience is not the same as mobile apps for wich you made the effort to download previously.

Switching website is easier than switching app.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint you but this can not be done as per Google's guidelines for advertising.

Refer: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en-GB#Placing_ads_in_pop-up_windows

Comment: Actually, I read that differently :( The user has to click the save button to show the pop up ! It's not just popping up. The user has to trigger an event. :/  Am I miss-reading it?